# Creating a custom PayPal donate form like this example

Tags: forms, paypal, payments

Looking to create a custom PayPal donate form like the one at https://www.battlefields.org/help-save-battlefields. On the PayPal site with the wizard for the donate button it doesn't allow more than 3 dollar amounts or custom fields like that. Assuming this is a custom implementation but not sure where to start. Do I need to store and process all the fields myself in a database, can I capture them and send with the PayPal API, or something else? Welcome any assistance!

Thanks,
Al

Comment: Looks like a https://www.drupal.org/ website with a Payment module https://www.drupal.org/project/payment. So yes you will have to process all fields in a database but a CMS can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'd be working with a Wordpress site. Any suggestions on a module/plugin for that platform?

Comment: https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/ off course!